# Using a Count Ifs statement in excel to Count how many time there is data within a range of dates

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Worksheet named "Data Sheet" and another work sheet named "Sheet1" which holds all my data. In "Data Sheet" worksheet on cell B3 it is supposed to count how many times there is a date that is between `1/01/2016` and `2/1/2016`. I am pulling the `1/01/2016` to `2/01/2016` dates from "Data Sheet" in column A. The dates its counting if its between that range is all of column F on "Sheet1"

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!F:F,">=A3",Sheet1!F:F,"<A4")
```

There is the formula I am using but it is not counting them. I have tried many variations of this to get it to work and cannot.

Here is a picture to get a little visual representation of what is going on.
[Screenshot of "Data Sheet"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQjBa.png)

[image: Data Sheet Screenshot]

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!F:F,">=" & A3,Sheet1!F:F,"<" & A4)` ?

Comment: I would Name the ranges `'Data Sheet'!A3` and `'Data Sheet'!A4` and use them in the formula.

Comment: @pnuts Sorry I was on wrong track what OP wants to do. Slai's the answer. Only Improvement is name the range `Sheet1!F:F`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!F:F,">="&A3,Sheet1!F:F,"<"&A4)

The only mistake you made was to include the range reference between double quotes. When you do this, Excel will interpret it as a string, so that's why you leave it out and use ampersand.